# How to convert a string in a dict in jinja2?

Tags: python, html, jinja2

I have {{data}} that is a string like this:
`*{"a": "1", "b": "2", "c": 3, "d": 4}*`

I would like to access it in this way:
`*{{data.a}} --> 1 {{data.b}} --> 2 *`
and so on.
I tried but it doesn't work.

How can I do that in jinja2?

Answer (score 0):

[Disclamer] My answer is not *"How to make it in Jinja"* but *"How to make"* bc I sencirely belive that this is not the best way and as far as I know there is no built in way to do so

I will assume that * symbols is your attempt to format cursive text and not a part of the strings.

If you want to serialize a string into dict, you could use json load string method.

```
#loads - stands for load (from) string
from json import loads
my_string = '{"a": "1", "b": "2", "c": 3, "d": 4}'
my_dict = loads(my_string)
```

And then you can pass it into the template and access it with

```
{{ my_dict["a"] }}
```

As far as I know from my experience it is better to serialize data from outside jinja and pass there ready data.